# SHAREPOINT 2013: How can I read Site column contents and modify them via javascript csom?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013, csom

I'm relative new to Sharepoint 2013, I'm trying to access and display on a page the contents inside a specific "Site Column", I've have been reading a lot about this, but I still can't accomplish my task. So far I get to this:

```
'use strict';
        var hostweburl;
        var appweburl;
        $(function () {
            SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(Function.createDelegate(this, function () {
                var currentcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();

                var web = currentcontext.get_web();

                //Get all fields in site collection
                var collFields = web.get_availableFields().getByTitle("EngineType_EngineCycle");

                currentcontext.load(collFields);

                currentcontext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, ExecuteOnSuccess), 
                Function.createDelegate(this, ExecuteOnFailure)); 
            }), 'SP.js'); 

            function ExecuteOnSuccess(sender, args) 
            { 
                var subsites = ''; 

                //for(int i=0; i< collF {
                //    if(collFields[i].Title == "siteColumnName"){
                //        alert("Got the Site col");
                //    }
                //}

            }
            function ExecuteOnFailure(sender, args) { 
                alert("error"); 
            } 
         });
```

But now I don't know ho to access/retrieve the data I need inside CollField, maybe I'm getting wrong somewhere? Please help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SP.FieldCollection object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246909.aspx) contains the following methods for getting [Field object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246815.aspx):

- [getById](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj247218.aspx) - gets the field with the specified ID
- [getByInternalNameOrTitle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246792.aspx) - returns the first Field object with the specified internal name or title from the collection
- [getByTitle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246244.aspx) - returns the first field object in the collection based on the title of the specified field

**Example**

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve site column:

```
function getSiteField(fieldName,success,failure)
{
     var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(); 
     var rootWeb = ctx.get_site().get_rootWeb(); 
     var field = rootWeb.get_availableFields().getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName);
     ctx.load(field);
     ctx.executeQueryAsync(
         function(){
            success(field)
         },
         failure);
}
```

**Usage**

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function() {

   //get Title column and print its properties
   getSiteField('Title',
    function(field){
       //print field properties
       console.log(field.get_title()); 
       console.log(field.get_internalName());
       console.log(field.get_typeAsString());
       console.log(field.get_description());
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    });

});
```

---

### How to update [Field object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246815.aspx)

The following example demonstrates to update `SP.FieldChoice` field properties:

```
function updateFieldChoice(fieldTitle,choiceValues,success,failure) {
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var fieldChoice = ctx.castTo(web.get_availableFields().getByTitle(fieldTitle), SP.FieldChoice);
    fieldChoice.set_choices(choiceValues);
    fieldChoice.update();
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
         function(){
            success(fieldChoice)
         },
         failure);
}
```

**Usage**

```
var choiceValues = ["Low", "Normal", "Critical"];

updateFieldChoice('RequestStatus',choiceValues,
    function(field){
       console.log('Choice field has been updated'); 
    },
    function(sender,args){
       console.log(args.get_message());
    });
```

Comment: Thanks very much.. one more question please.. if I wanna update the content of a site column with the content of an array how can I do? (example my site column contains values as 1 2 3 4 5 and I have my array with 1 2 2 4 5).

Comment: Sure, the answer has been updated, it demonstrates how to set choice values for SP.FieldChoice field

Comment: sorry I can't understand how to implement that, can you be so kind to refer to this please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29964007/sharepoint-2013-how-can-i-update-a-site-column-with-the-content-of-an-array-wit

Comment: No worries, could you please clarify just one moment, should this script be executed from App page (part of SharePoint App) or from Host web (SharePoint page)?

Comment: It's a web part displayed ina SharePoint Page, thanks a lot!!